# Java Cannot find symbol in same for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

In the following code, the variable `number` cannot be found in the line `number++` even though I initialized `number` in the same for-loop. Can anyone tell me why?

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;

public class test
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
        String cardNumber; 
        double cardRandom;
        int cardRandomNumber;
        String[] cardSelection = new String[10];

        for (int number = 0; number <=  9; );
        {
            Random ran = new Random();
            cardRandom = ran.nextInt(52 - 1 + 1) + 1;
            cardRandomNumber = (int) Math.round( cardRandom );

            if ( cardRandomNumber > 0 && cardRandomNumber <= 52 )
            { 
                cardNumber =  "card" + cardRandomNumber;
                System.out.println( cardNumber );
                number++; // Says Error: Cannot find symbol
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

This program basically just picks a random number from 1-52, adds "cards" to the beginning of it and prints it out. It should print out 10 numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last semicolon in the following line must go away:

```
for (int number = 0; number <=  9; );
```

You basically declare a `for` loop without body. Good IDE should warn you about such bugs. And BTW incrementing loop counter should go to the last `for` expression where we all expect it to be:

```
for (int number = 0; number <=  9; ++number) {
  //..
}
```

BTW after eliminating unnecessary variables and conditions that are always met your code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int number = 0; number <= 9; ++number) {
        int cardRandom = 1 + r.nextInt(52);
        String cardNumber = "card" + cardRandom;
        System.out.println(cardNumber);
    }
}
```

Seriously.

Comment: Nice cleanup, but don't create a new Random instance each time. Unless you specify a seed, Randoms are seeded with the value of System.currentTimeMillis(). If you create a new Random each time, you'll end up picking the same card whenever a loop iteration takes less than 1 millisecond to complete.

Comment: @dnault ... and even if it takes more than 1ms per iteration, still, just use a single `Random`.

Comment: @dnault: +1, absolutely, fixed. Just mindlessly copied from original.

Answer (score 2):

You've inadvertently terminated your `for` loop with a trailing semicolon:

```
for (int number = 0; number <=  9; );
```

This makes it equivalent to:

```
for (int number = 0; number <=  9; )
{ ; }

{
    Random ran = new Random();
    cardRandom = ran.nextInt(52 - 1 + 1) + 1;
    cardRandomNumber = (int) Math.round( cardRandom );

    // etc. ...
```

And so the `number` variable is out of scope when you increment it.

Remove that trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon:

```
for (int number = 0; number <=  9; ); // <-- this is your problem
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.Random; 
public class foo 
{
    public static void main( String [] args ) 
    {

        String cardNumber;          
        double cardRandom;       
        int cardRandomNumber;       
        String[] cardSelection = new String[10];   
        for (int number = 0; number <=  9; )
        {
            Random ran = new Random();   
            cardRandom = ran.nextInt(52 - 1 + 1) + 1;         
            cardRandomNumber = (int) Math.round( cardRandom );    



            if ( cardRandomNumber > 0 && cardRandomNumber <= 52 )          
            {     
                cardNumber =  "card" + cardRandomNumber;               
                System.out.println( cardNumber );      
            }
            number++; 
        }
    }   
}
```

The output is a set of 10 items:(notice that every time you run the program ,it gives different card numbers)

card2
card12
card37
card23
card18
card20
card21
card45
card19
card13